# jQuery Validate Textfield against two or more values

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a textfield against two or more values:

```
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
    return arg !== value;
}, "Value must not equal arg.");
```

Here is the validation:

```
wp_permalink: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 100,
    valueNotEquals: "hi there",
    valueNotEquals: "hey there"
}
```

The code works fine when I have only one value that I'm comparing against, but as soon as I add the second it breaks.

How can I validate against two or more values?

Comment: Have you tried `valueNotEquals: [ 'value1', 'value2' ]`?  An object can't repeat keys at the very least, so your attempt at using the same key twice is an obvious error

Comment: You cannot set the same rule twice.  Makes no sense.  There is one rule that gets one set of parameters.  See comment above mine.  Rewrite your custom method/rule to accept multiple parameters.  Browse through [the code in the Additional Methods file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/additional-methods.js) to see how multiple parameters are handled in other methods.